# How to use value returned from fabric.api.local() in fabric.context_managers.prefix()

Tags: python, fabric

How to get a location of a folder with `local()` and execute commands in this folder with `prefix()`

My code:

```
from fabric.api import local
from fabric.context_managers import prefix


def deploy_user_service():
    directory = str(local("find ~ -type d -name \"user-service\"", capture=True))
    cd_prefix = "cd " + directory
    with prefix(cd_prefix):
        local("mvn clean package")
```

My execution:

```
➜  user-service git:(user-service-deploy-script) ✗ fab deploy_user_service
[localhost] local: find ~ -type d -name "user-service"
[localhost] local: mvn clean package
/bin/sh: line 1: /Users/raitis.dembovskis/ww/user-service: is a directory

Fatal error: local() encountered an error (return code 126) while executing 'mvn clean package'

Aborting.
```

It seems that in the end value that gets passed to `prefix()` is just `"/Users/raitis.dembovskis/ww/user-service"` without `"cd "`

Comment: how about `with cd('/path/to/app'):` - doc: http://docs.fabfile.org/en/1.13/api/core/context_managers.html

Comment: there is also `lcd` for local folders - http://docs.fabfile.org/en/1.13/api/core/context_managers.html#fabric.context_managers.lcd